# Javascript Function is not working when calling from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, flash

I have this javascript function inside a .aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function somefun(value) {
        document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsUrl", value);
        document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsPlay", "");
    }
```

It **works perfectly** when I call it *inside the body of the .aspx page* like this.

```
<button onclick="somefun('Audio/filename.mp3')">English</button>
```

But if I call it in the **code behind** inside a click event it gives an error.

```
protected void theClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath1 = "Audio/filename.mp3";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "Registering", String.Format("somefun('{0}');", filePath1), true);
    }
```

When I click the button I'm getting this error: **'Unable to get property 'SetVariable' of undefined or null reference'**

The *object I call by "myflash"* is

```
<object id="myFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="1093" height="52" >
```

What would be the issue?

**Edited:**

```
<head runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function somefun(value) {

        alert(document.getElementById("myFlash"));

        document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsUrl", value);
        document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsPlay", "");

    }
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text = "Download"   runat="server" OnClick = "theClickEvent"></asp:LinkButton>         
</form>


<object id="myFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="1093" height="52" style="margin-left:0%">

</object>
```

Comment: Your code is running too early.

Comment: @SLaks didn't get you. What do you mean by 'running too early'?

Comment: It's running before the elements exist.

Comment: @SLaks What would be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the JavaScript code in your Button's click event, it doesn't execute the code at that time.

Your client side code `onclick="somefun('Audio/filename.mp3')"` executes before you register the script with script manager.

Use your code block within `Page_Load` instead of button click event.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the Flash object takes time to load or you click before it loads. To avoid this you could do the following.

1. Disable the link button until the DOM (or Document in JavaScript) is ready
2. When DOM/ Document is ready enable the button using JavaScript.
3. Also it's a good practice to do a Null check before accessing any of the properties of elements

Hope this helps

Comment: <button onclick="somefun('Audio/filename.mp3')">English</button> works anyway.    I have another button inside a form with runat="server" which has the 'theClickEvent' function. That causes the issue

Comment: Ok. Anyway, add ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock ... code block that is currently in you click event to Page_Load. It should work then

Comment: Just add alert(document.getElementById("myFlash")); as your first statement in the JavaScript function and let me know the message you get. You may have to run the website using ctrl + F5 to get the latest JavaScript.

Comment: Ok that's the issue. "myFlash" object is not visible (not loaded to DOM) at the time you click that button. You can see this by going to view source. Please update your question with the markup code having this object and the button.